# Why doesn't my Sieve of Eratosthenes c++ implementation print anything when sieving above 46349

Tags: c++, c++20, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to make a Sieve of Eratosthenes using C++, however, my program, whenever a number 46350 or higher is input as the top end of the sieve range it simply outputs nothing. It seems to, for any lower number work exactly as intended.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#define squarert 46350 // I found that it doesn't give correct answers if the "squareroot" number is actually the square root of the second number.
#define num squarert
#define size 10001
std::array < long long, size > eSieve ()
{
    std::array < long long, size > primes;    //array declared
    std::array < bool, num > numbers;
    for(int i = 2; i < squarert; i++) {
        numbers[i] = true;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= squarert; i++) {
        if (numbers[i]) {
            for(int j = i * i; j < num; j += i) {
                numbers[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(numbers[i]) {
            primes[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    
  return primes;        //array returned
}

int
main ()
{
    std::array<long long,size> arr;
    
    arr=eSieve(); //function call
    for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I realize that this is incredibly janky, I was just trying to get a working sieve and then improve the readability.

I tried trial and error to find the exact number at which the program broke, which is 46350. At that number or higher it just completes with exit code 0 and has no output in the console. I can't find anything online related to this number, and it doesn't seem to be anything special in binary. I'm using C++ 20 on onlinegdb.

Comment: So what is `count` right before it stops working?

Comment: What’s 46350 squared (`i * i`)?  (What is it in hexadecimal?)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried to use `std::cout<<count<<" ";` at the end of the last for loop in eSieve and run it and nothing came out of the console.

Comment: @DavisHerring in decimal it's 2148322 and in hex it's 20C7E2

Comment: @Linkman8912: That’s missing some (decimal ) digits: it’s 2,148,322,500 (0x800CCCC4).

Comment: @DavisHerring yeah I must have pasted it wrong

Comment: The shown code runs off the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior, and [demons flying out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). The last value of `i` for `numbers[i]`, in the 2nd `for` loop will be `squarert`, since the loop condition is `<=`, a.k.a. `num`. Fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I'm really glad you caught that. I tried it, and it doesn't fix the issue though.

Comment: Start fixing stuff in this: https://godbolt.org/z/bGnYvanYP . Make the tools work for you by jacking up the compiler diagnostics and turning on extra runtime checking. If you have a toolchain that supports sanitizers, do the work on your computer, but if not, praise be Matt Godbolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had an integer overflow error and had to change variable `j` to a long long.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).